# Arduino - Variables declared in setup() not in scope of function

Tags: c++, arduino

I planned to write a function that modifies a two-dimensional array so that each coordinate is set to 0. In `setup()` I declared the `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` but can't access them in the `generateBoard()` function because they aren't in the same scope.

### The code:

```
void generateBoard(int board[][]) {
  // Modifies the array board by setting zeros

  for (int y=0; y < displayHeight; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x < displayWidth; x++) {
      board[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  int displayWidth  = 14;
  int displayHeight = 10;

  int board[displayWidth][displayHeight];
  generateBoard(board); 
}

void loop() {}
```

**Exception with local scope inside setup()**

```
error: declaration of 'board' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
error: declaration of 'board' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
In function 'void generateBoard(...)':
error: 'displayHheight' was not declared in this scope
error: 'displayWidth' was not declared in this scope
error: 'board' was not declared in this scope
```

---

### Fixed and working version:

```
const int displayWidth  = 14;
const int displayHeight = 10;
int board[displayWidth][displayHeight];

void generateBoard() {
  // Modifies the array board by setting zeros

  for (int y=0; y < displayHeight; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x < displayWidth; x++) {
      board[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  generateBoard(); 
}

void loop(){}
```

Comment: Correct. Because that's how C++ works.

Comment: How can I fix it? The reference of Arduino says: *The setup() function is called when a sketch starts. Use it to **initialize variables***

Comment: That's declaration, not initialization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arduino: error: 'abs' was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965025/arduino-error-abs-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `board`, `displayWidth`, and `displayHeight` globally (outside of any function definition). Like this:

```
 const int displayWidth  = 14;
 const int displayHeight = 10;
 int board[displayWidth][displayHeight];

void generateBoard() {
  // Modifies the array board by setting 0

  for (int y=0; y < displayHeight; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x < displayWidth; x++) {
      board[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  generateBoard(); 
}

void loop() {}
```

Declaring them inside of setup() makes them local variables - local variables are only accessible to the function in which they are declared.